# CSS + Jquery - How can I get this effect? (popup a div when mouse go over)

Tags: javascript, css

Im looking for doing somethings like this : open a div (with some data) when i go over some content with mouse.

You can see an example [here](http://www.inter.it/aas/squadra/index?L=it) : go over the small photo with mouse : you can see a div-popup that move within the mouse's position.

As suggested, this is possible with css+js(jquery. How can I do it? Is not so clear the JS file in the page, that's why i ask any helps :)

Cheers

Comment: Can't be done with pure CSS, so I've added the `javascript` tag to your question.

Comment: Thanks man ;) In fact i thought so...

Comment: @Brad - not true - it can be done with CSS only, but he's using js probalby because he's also adding and removing title attribute.

Comment: In fact, it can be done in pure CSS, but it's a lot easier and more flexible with JS/JQuery. (the pure CSS option would involve having the popup div inside the mouse-over div in the DOM, but positioned absolutely and z-indexed so it can be displayed elsewhere on the page)

Comment: Again - don't agree - it's pretty simple to do and you just have to give who the relative element is - and what's so scary about z-index? Its a normal css property.

Comment: @all, I stand corrected. @easwee, why don't you give us an answer/example?

Comment: @easwee.  I have checked the code and the image preview is handled in javascript look at line 111 of generic.js, which is executed in the document.ready on line 178 of index

Comment: Actually you are right - didn't see he's asking for mouse movement too...you can't position relative to mouse with css.

Comment: @markzzz.  I just gave you the line numbers of the code from the web page you provided.  Look at the javascript.  Note this webpage uses Jquery.

Comment: Yes i see, but is not so clear understand how it works. that's why i open this topic:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is quite simple. You need three things: an absolutely positioned div that's not nested in anything else (parent is `<body>`), a mousemove event handler to show the div and move it around, and a mouseleave handler to hide it.

With jQuery you can easily get the mouse coordinates from within any event handler: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position

```
// Get all elements you want a "popup" for
$(".popup")
// Attach a mousemove handler
.mousemove(function (e) {

   // Is there a absolutely positioned popup div already?
   // If not, create one and append to body
   var $popup = $("#popup");
   if (! $popup.length) {
      $popup = $("<div id='popup'>").appendTo("body");
   }

   // Position the popup by mouse coordinates, and make sure it's shown
   $popup.css({left: e.pageX + 20, top: e.pageY + 20}).show();
})
// Attach mouseleave handler to hide the popup
.mouseleave(function () {
   $("#popup").hide();
});
```

And you'll want this CSS:

```
#popup {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background: #aaa; /* Just so you can see it */
}
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/yEeyV/

Answer (score 2):

This works, but the positioning in your example is done with javascript I think.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
    <head>

        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            .popup{
                display: none;
            }

            .small:hover .popup{
                display: block;
            }


        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="small">
            <div class="popup">
                this is the popup
            </div>
            this is the trigger
        </div>
        <div class="small">
            <div class="popup">
                this is the 2nd popup
            </div>
            this is the 2nd trigger
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The div would have to be there, but invisible `display:none`

Through CSS you create a hover nested rule:

```
div.withdata:hover div.helper {display:block}

<div class="withdata"><img ...><div class="helper"></div></div>
```

Good Luck!

Comment: The image won't float with your mouse, but it can be displayed in a static position

Comment: How would this allow OP to "...div-popup that move within the mouse position"?  It can't be done with just CSS, JavaScript is needed.

Comment: I didn't think that was the core of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use JQuery Tooltips : http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/